# How to fit Sklearn Pipeline on Catboost Classifier with Embedding features

Tags: scikit-learn, embedding, catboost, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have a Catboost Classifier that predicts on some embedding features, and AFAIK these embedding features can only be specified through Pools (meaning I have to create a pool and then pass the pool for the Catboost classifier's `.fit` method in order for the model to pick them up).

These embedding features are generated by a `TfidfVectorizer`, so I would like to wrap the `TfidfVectorizer` and the classifier as part of an sklearn `Pipeline` to tidy up my code and have a clear pipeline to train/predict.

Unfortunately, I cannot pass Catboost `Pool` to an sklearn `Pipeline` because when I do, I get the following error:

```
Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=<catboost.core.Pool object at 0x7f98f0256820>.
```

Is there any way around this?